# Android studio XML changes not reflecting after rebuild

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, android-layout, rebuild

So when I change a text view colour, or add a text or anything in the xml layout file, and after that i simply run the app, nothing changes until I Clean->Rebuild->Run.

Android Studio 3.4
I have multiple flavors in my application (might be the reason).

[image]

What I want is :
1. **Either a script or some setting to clean-rebuild-run at a single button**
or
2. **A setting to not ignore the xml changes**
or
3. **A solution where I do not have to clean-rebuild each time**

Answer (score 0):

Try to disable `instant run` and check that can help.

> **File → Settings → Build, Execution, Deployment → Instant Run and uncheck Enable Instant Run.**